# D3 Categorical Area Chart - Scale Issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create an area chart for statistics on each US state. I have a single number statistic for each state; an element of my data list looks like the following:

```
{'state':'CA','count':4000}
```

Currently, my area chart looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLPq7.jpg). The task is mainly complete, but you may notice how the very last category (in this case, UTAH) isn't filled. I'm not quite sure how to get around this. [close_up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKsV1.jpg)

I am using a scaleBand axis; this felt appropriate. Perhaps it is not the correct approach. Here is the JS behind the chart:

```
var svg_area = d3.select("#area")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom),
g_area = svg_area.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var area = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.state); })
  .y0(height)
  .y1(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

d3.csv('data/states.csv', function(data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.count = +d.count;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.count-a.count;
  });

  data = data.slice(0,30);

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.state; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

  g_area.append('path')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('fill', solar[1])
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr('d', area);

  g_area.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x-axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g_area.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y-axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 0 + ")")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
});
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: can you also share your data...may be data for utah may be 0..?

Comment: @Cyril all states have nonzero counts; Utah's is 1866.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to your question's title (now edited), the area chart is not *"leaving out the last data point"*.

What you're seeing is the expected result, since you are using a band scale. Actually, that value just above the horizontal axis (just in the "edge" of the area chart) **is** Utah value! Try to understanding it with this explanation: Imagine a bar chart with your data. Each bar has, of course, a given width. Now, draw a path going from the **top left** corner of one bar to the **top left** corner of the next bar, starting at the first bar and, when reaching the last bar, going down from the top left corner to the axis. That's the area you have right now.

There are two solutions here. The first one is using a point scale instead:

```
var x = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width])
```

However, this will trim the "margins" of the area path, before the first state and after the last state (Utah). That means, the area chart will start right over California tick and end right over Utah tick.

If you don't want that there is a second solution, which is hacky, but will keep those "margins": add the `bandwidth()` to the last state in the area generator:

```
var area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d, i) {
        return i === data.length - 1 ?
            x(d.state) + x.bandwidth() : x(d.state)
    })
```

It may be worth noting that, using a band scale, your chart is technically incorrect: the values in the area for each state are not over the tick for that state.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation about what was going on! And you're definitely right on that final remark; point scale was the way to go in this case.